# A memorial Georgia (U.S.) plaque

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military

This [memorial plaque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGeorgia_salutes_soldiers.jpg) lists the numbers of Georgians who served in various wars and details the casualties. What I find odd is that for WWI, Korea, Vietnam, and Gulf round numbers are given for the participants, whereas for WWII a strangely exact number is given - 324373. The lists of casualties do not appear to be rounded throughout.

Is there an explanation for this oddness?

Comment: my guess is they'd use conscription numbers for WW2, while for the other wars there was a large section of professional troops where it's hard to tell whether they're from your state or not. Do you count birth, last home as a civilian, or last US based posting before being sent overseas?

Comment: @jwenting: This sounds like a (good) answer. Why don't you post it as one?

Comment: 1) I've no evidence, it's based on my knowledge of the makeup of the US armed forces in those conflicts. 2) it'd just get downvoted by the usual suspects anyway.

Comment: Maybe I'm OCD, but I found odd the "0 MIA" in the 5th bullet point: they could have just omitted that, it's not a table! Technically they are saluting, among the others, that group of 0 soldiers, too.

Comment: @Lohoris this way preserves the symmetry of the table, of there were nothing there people'd complain about that, or think the number had faded somehow.

Comment: @jwenting sure, but I'm not talking about the table, I'm talking about the upper part, which isn't a table, hence no symmetry to preserve (and there are some spare entries, such as the "13 Remains ID" in the Vietnam bullet point)